# How can I identify the element containing the link to my linkedin profile after I logged in using selenium.webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have written a script (python) to login to my LinkedIn page (feed) and then I want the script to take me to my profile page. But I cannot capture the element with the link (it keeps changing its id with every restart of the browser). Obviously, I know the link but I would like for the script to be able to capture it.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import parameters
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/uglyr/chromedriver')  
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')

username = driver.find_element_by_id('session_key')
username.send_keys(parameters.linkedin_username)

sleep(0.5)    

password = driver.find_element_by_id('session_password')
password.send_keys(parameters.linkedin_password)

sleep(0.5)

log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sign-in-form__submit-button')
log_in_button.click()

sleep(1)
```

this takes me to my feed page.

Any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `a` element of interest does have a changing `id="emberXX"`, but you can use the `parent`  keyword from selenium on its `div` child:

```
profile = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-control-name='identity_profile_photo']/parent::a")
profile.click()
```

should take you to your profile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ids of the elements are not getting changed. But still you can try with xpath which does not contain id.

I hope following code lines will help:

*menu_icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//button[@data-control-name='nav.settings']//child::span[1])*
*menu_icon.click()*

*profile_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//button[@data-control-name='nav.settings']//following-sibling::div[1])*
*profile_link.click()*